# CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an ionic app trying to update the records in firebase. I keep on getting this error. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: a custom Object object
>
> FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: a custom Object object

this is my update function.

```
updateTodo(todo: Todo, id: string) {

    return this.todosCollection.doc(id).update(todo)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the value of `id`?  Use a debugger or log the value to show exactly what you're passing.

Comment: Are you sure that your `id` is not null or empty?

Comment: I had a similar issue which I solved by correcting the doc reference, which in your case is the "id". Just make sure that the value of "id" in your code is a valid reference string for a firebase document.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are trying to send an empty object to firebase.
I had this error when I reset my form values before the async call could finish..

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was passing a number type variable in the .doc function but it requires a string. Verify that your "id" variable has a value and it is not undefined, null or and empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the id that you are passing in doc,it is supposed to be a string..try logging its value just to check what you are exactly passing

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

Go where you're calling that function updateTodo use uid instead of id.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This seem to be a comment but not an answer. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and solved it by typing .doc(cred.user.**uid**) instead of .doc(cred.user.**id**).